# Boolean modifier difference not engraving correctly

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to make some custom chess pieces.

I am just trying to engrave some images onto the chess piece but when I use the boolean difference modifier, the piece goes crazy and doesn't really engrave it properly.

It seems to cut out faces weirdly and I also have to align the pieces up a certain way, or it won't even apply the modifier at all.

I am trying to figure out how to attach the blend file, but I can't find the button.

Any help with this would be great please!! Complete blender newbie here :(

[image]

Comment: Thanks,think I finally got the upload working now :)

Comment: The appropriate method will depend a bit on what your final use of the model will be (to make images, to 3D print...) .. so perhaps you could edit your question to include that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems because you need to clean up a bit your meshes:

- Select your symbol object, go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.
- Also press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*.
- Select your cylinder, go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.
- Give your cylinder a *Boolean* modifier, choose *Operation* > *Difference*, and select your symbol as *Object*.
- It works (well, it will need a bit of topology work)

[image]

Comment: I should really get over my Boolean allergy :D

Comment: I've learnt how to appreciate it   ;)

Comment: you should check the amazing Speedflow addon, unfortunately it's not free but it makes hardsurface works really fun.

Comment: Thx for reminding me ..  I haven't tried it yet, your recommendation gives me more confidence.. by the look of it, Lepiller deserves every penny. I wouldn't have thought that adds up to much per hour..