# Boolean Difference Modifier not applying consistently (see pic)

Tags: modifiers

Thought it would be fun to create some 3D printed keyrings for my business and seem to have got stuck at the first or second hurdle.

I'm trying to use the boolean difference modifier to engrave some text on the actual keyring object, but it seems to be inconsistent in some of the vertical edges/faces.

By looking at the image below you'll see that the vertical edges in the number "1" are previewing in orange meaning they'll be created. Notice the vertical edges on numbers "3" and "5" are black, and will not be created.

I can confirm that after applying the modifier it does exactly what I just mentioned. "1"s are engraved perfectly, but "3"s and "5"s are missing the vertical edges and faces between the bottom of the engraving and the front face of main object.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating your problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFYn8.png. But I have had my fair share of Boolean misbehavior. Would you consider sharing your Blender file?

Comment: By the way, this might help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131035/boolean-modifier-difference-not-engraving-correctly?rq=1 If nothing else the first comment describes how to share a Blender file.